# Plugin de Captcha para Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

He estado buscando sobre cómo implementar un captcha en los formularios de un sitio web. Concretamente usé reCaptcha de Google usando la API proporcionada por el mismo. Todo ello lo realicé en un solo tema de Wordpress y debo pasar esos cambios a un nuevo tema.

Para evitar ésto me solicitaron usar un plugin para que no afecte cuando se decida cambiar a otro tema.

El problema es que los únicos que he encontrado son para la venta de login al tablero de wordpress y para comentarios de los post de los usuarios, ninguno para formularios.

¿Alguien conoce el nombre o la implementado algo parecido?

Comment: Hola @AlejandroSanchez, tu pregunta parece no tratar sobre programación sino sobre uso de Wordpress, además que las recomendaciones de software no tienen una respuesta objetiva lo cual no va con la temática del sitio: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/195/20

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz creo que esta pregunta segun se mire prodria estar en el limite, pero no sabria decirte. Pero la verdad que de este tipo de desarrollos no se, pero dice de implemetar usando la API... eso no se tiene que programar mediante codigo o tiene esa opcion  (mi punto de vista).  Saludos

Comment: Independientemente de si se trate de programación de plugins para wordpress o simplemente de la instalación de uno, no hay una respuesta objetiva ya que pueden haber muchos plugins que hagan lo que @Alejandro necesita

Comment: Considero que la pregunta está dentro del scope

Comment: @JuanK el problema no es el tema de la pregunta sino que se trata de una recomendación de software.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quiza te sirva Captcha by [BestWebSoft](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/captcha/)

Para usarlo necesitas:

- Descargar y descomprimir la carpeta en tu equipo
- Subirlo a tu sitio a la ruta `/wp-content/plugins/`
- Activarlo en el menu 'Plugins'

La configuracion deberia aparecer en `Plugins -> BWS Plugins -> Captcha`

Comment: Gracias, fue el que implemente. Muy sencillo y facil de usar, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El plugin [Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA)](https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/google-captcha/) muestra usarse en formularios como los citados en la documentación oficial que bien parece cubrir lo que requieres y aparte mantiene (ante la vista del cliente) la misma forma.

Según la documentación oficial

**Características**

- Soporte estándar para formularios WordPress:

  - Registro.
  - Login.
  - Re-establecer contraseña.
  - Formularios (otros).
  - Comentarios.
- Compatible con "Contact Form" by BestWebSoft.
- Oculta Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA) para ciertos roles de usuario.
- Soporta la versión 1 y 2 de Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA).
- Soporte estándar de temas para Google Captcha (reCAPTCHA).